# Checking if an overridden parent method exists before calling it

Tags: php

How would I go about ensuring that the overridden parent method exists before I call it?
I've tried this:

```
public function func() {
    if (function_exists('parent::func')) {
        return parent::func();
    }
}
```

However the function_exists never evaluates to true.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The way to do that, is:

```
if (method_exists(get_parent_class($this), 'func')) {
    // method exist
} else {
   // doesn't
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-parent-class.php

Comment: method_exists doesn't work with parent, thanks though.  For some reason I remember getting function_exists to work before, but it isn't now...

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure what you are trying to do.  Perhaps you could combine it with get_parent class - something like this:

method_exists(get_parent_class($this), 'func')

I may be barking up the wrong tree though.

Comment: Ah, that actually works... once.  It needs to loop to go any higher then the first parent.

Comment: `get_parent_class` will return false once it hits the last ancestor.  A simple while loop will do the trick.  It's still an ugly hack, of course.

Comment: Mike's answer in the comments is what I ended up with.

Comment: @mike, could you please edit your anwser and add `get_parent_class($this)` into anwser?

Answer (score 35):

```
public function func() 
{
    if (is_callable('parent::func')) {
        parent::func();
    }
}
```

I use this for calling parent constructor if exists, works fine.

I also use the following as a generic version:

```
public static function callParentMethod(
    $object,
    $class,
    $methodName,
    array $args = []
) {
    $parentClass = get_parent_class($class);
    while ($parentClass) {
        if (method_exists($parentClass, $methodName)) {
            $parentMethod = new \ReflectionMethod($parentClass, $methodName);
            return $parentMethod->invokeArgs($object, $args);
        }
        $parentClass = get_parent_class($parentClass);
    }
}
```

use it like this:

```
callParentMethod($this, __CLASS__, __FUNCTION__, func_get_args());
```

Comment: the `if (is_callable('parent::func')) parent::func();` solution is great, if C extends B and B extends A and C::Foo checks for parent::Bar and Bar is declared in A but not in B it still works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class super {
    public function m() {}
}

class sub extends super {
     public function m() {
        $rc = new ReflectionClass(__CLASS__);
        $namepc = $rc->getParentClass()->name;
        return method_exists($namepc, __FUNCTION__);
    }
}

$s = new sub;
var_dump($s->m());
```

gives `bool(true)`. Not sure if this would work if the method was defined in a superclass of `super`, but it would be a matter of introducing a simple loop.

Comment: Mike's get_parent_class method accomplishes the same thing, without Reflection.